# Failed to execute child

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I made some sort of error trying to install software. Now my terminal is stuck with this error message

[image]

How can I clear it to use it again? I can't type anything in terminal. I think I found which version/release I am using: Xubunto 18.04.3 LTS *Bionic Beaver*-Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe  I need to install music writing software and scanning software.

**Failed to execute child**
Failed to execute child process "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" (No such file or directory)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please post the full output of the command.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please let us know what error you think you made, what software you were trying to install (and how) and what version of Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I am using Ubuntu. How do I find out which release or version of Ubuntu I have?

Comment: Click on the down arrow at the top right of the screen, then settings, then at the bottom left ‘about’. Or open the dock, search ‘about’ and it will pop up. Or open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) and type lsb_release -a

Comment: Pilot6 & Will - the versiion/release is Xubunto 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_-Release amd64 (20190805)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe

Comment: You do minor edits, but never posted the full output of the command. If you don't add information, the question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: Pilot6 as far as I know, the full output of the command was "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" Is there a way to get you the info that you need?

Comment: @CarolLeaWhite I have edited your question to embed your picture link. It would be helpful to mention what software you are trying to install and where you obtained it

Comment: Looks like you are trying to execute commands in the wrong place. This might work better if you undo everything that you have previously done, and then ask a question about installing the actual software that you really want. As written, seems to resemble an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" is the *input* that you gave. We need to see the *output* that printed out after that.

Comment: And it is unclear to me where the command is entered. It does not look like a terminal.

Comment: Organic Marble - there was no output, only the error message.

Comment: user535733 - I would Love to undo everything that I have previously done. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there something I can do in Task Manager, or by deleting some files?

Comment: I went back into my notes to see what I was trying to do when I put in this command. I was trying to play an mp4 video. per Abhishek Prakash, I was trying to change the software sources and add Canonical Partners in it to increase the number of applications and programs in my repository and so I can easily install them via Ubuntu Software Center or command line per Abhishek Prakash. Here are the commands I typed into the terminal:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras for media codecs:
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras